# Displaying Images in folder asp.net core dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display all the images in a images folder I have stored in the root file. I know they have vaulted the Server.MapPath method in asp.net core. I am not sure how I would do the same functionality in .net core of creating a view model and being able to loop through all the images stored in my root images folder. Any suggestions would be great. Below is the example code I was going off of but it obviously doesn't work for.Net core.

```
// model
class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }
}

// controller
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel()
{
    Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images_upload"))
                      .Select(fn => "~/images_upload/" + 
   Path.GetFileName(fn))
};
return View(model);
}
// view
@foreach(var image in Model.Images)
  {
     <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" />
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`IHostingEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.0), which you should get injected into your Controller if you specify it in the constructor.

You can then use the properties (depending on where you put your images_upload folder):

- **ContentRootPath** - application's base path. This is the location of
  the web.config, project.json
- **WebRootPath** - the physical file path to
  the directory that houses files intended to be browsable. By default,
  this is the wwwroot folder

Then use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`

e.g.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        var folderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "/images_upload");
        var model = new MyViewModel()
        {
            Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
                .Select(filename => folderPath + filename)
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```